# Recursion - boolean and large signal

Tags: java, recursion

If all the large characters in the string, the function returns true
Otherwise false.

I have a problem how to check if the character is a capital letter or not.

compile error in line:

```
(str.charAt(n-1) != check)
```

the eror:

```
The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) char, boolean
```

The code:

```
public static boolean ifCharBig(String str,int n){  
    boolean check =Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(n));
    if (n == 0)
        return true;
    if (str.charAt(n-1) != check)
        return false;

    return ifCharBig(str, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: You are trying to compare a `character` with a `boolean`. That is the source of the compilation error.

Comment: The error speaks for itself. If you explain what you're trying to do with that line, maybe we can help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line: `if (str.charAt(n-1) != check)`? Why `n-1` specifically? What are you trying to check?

Comment: More important question: Why are you using recursion for a task that is NOT recursive by nature, but iterative?  If I give you a 10,000 character string you would almost surely get a `StackOverflowExcaption`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it:

```
public static boolean ifCharBig(String str){
    return ifCharBig(str, str.length() - 1);
}
public static boolean ifCharBig(String str, int n){
    if (n == -1)
        return true;
    return Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(n)) && ifCharBig(str, n - 1);
}


System.out.println(ifCharBig("fOo"));
System.out.println(ifCharBig("fOO"));
System.out.println(ifCharBig("FOO"));
```

**Output:**

```
false
false
true
```

Indeed you have 2 problems in your code:

1. You try to compare a `char` with a `boolean` which are incompatible primitive types.
2. You make your method exit if `n` is `0` which is a mistake since `0` is a valid index so it should be treated as a normal case.